# How to get the list of running only?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

I need to get the RUNNING IP's from the AWS only, the function pulls only the IP's listed as EIP which include Non-associated ones too.

```
def gather_public_ip():
   ACCESS_KEY = config.get('aws','access_key')
   SECRET_KEY = config.get('aws','secret_key')
   regions = ['ap-northeast-1']
   all_EIP = []
   for region in regions:
      client = boto3.client('ec2',aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,region_name=region,)
      addresses_dict = client.describe_addresses()
      for eip_dict in addresses_dict['Addresses']:
          print eip_dict['PublicIp']

          return eip_dict['PublicIp']
```

Can someone help me out??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get that from the following queries

- To get the list of Private IP for running instance

`aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=instance-state-code, Values=16" --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].PrivateIpAddress" --output text`

- To get the list of Public IP for running instance

`aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=instance-state-code, Values=16" --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].PublicIpAddress" --output text`

To transform into python code you could do something like

```
response = client.describe_instances(
    Filters=[
        {
            'Name': 'instance-state-code',
            'Values': [
                '16',
            ]
        },
    ],)
```

Then you will need to read the JSON output about `Reservations[*].Instances[*].PrivateIpAddress` and `Reservations[*].Instances[*].PublicIPAddress`

The definition / possible values for `instance-state-code` are

> The state of the instance, as a 16-bit unsigned
>   integer. The high byte is an opaque internal value and should be
>   ignored. The low byte is set based on the state represented. The valid
>   values are: 0 (pending), 16 (running), 32 (shutting-down), 48
>   (terminated), 64 (stopping), and 80 (stopped).

Answer (score 0):

As shown below you need to filter out the running instances by looking at the reservations / instances data.  Also I've added a check for if the host has a public ip

```
e = client.describe_instances()
for r in e['Reservations']:
    if r['Instances'][0]['State']['Name'] == 'running'\
    and 'PublicIpAddress' in r['Instances'][0]:
        print r['Instances'][0]['PublicIpAddress']
```

Comment: would have been better to edit my python code than making your own answer, its basically the same answer as I did.

Comment: Your answer is very much cleverer than my humble effort.  Best to leave things as they are

Answer (score 0):

The associated EIP will have a corresponding `PrivateIpAddress`. If EIP is not associated, the eip_dict will not have a `PrivateIpAddress`. So just add an extra check to your code:

```
  for eip_dict in addresses_dict['Addresses']:
      if 'PrivateIpAddress' in eip_dict:
          print eip_dict['PublicIp']
```

This will print all elastic ip addresses that are associated - whether the instance is running or not. If you really want the elastic ip address of running instances only, then you have to apply another filter. Use the solution proposed by Vorsprung to get the running instances and filter the list.